# Understanding Haskell seq

Tags: haskell

I'm a Haskell newbie having problems understanding `seq`, which I've summarized in the example below.

Here are 2 implementations of the same (silly) function. The function takes a positive int n and returns the tuple `(n,n)`. The answer is produced by counting up from `(0,0)` using a helper function with a tuple accumulator. To avoid building up a large thunk I used seq to make the accumulator strict.

In `testSeq1` the contents of the tuple are strict, whereas in `testSeq2` the tuple itself is strict. I thought these 2 implementations would perform identically. But actually the 'total memory in use' is only 1MB for `testSeq1` but a massive 187MB for `testSeq2` (when tested using n = 1000000).

What's wrong with `testSeq2`?

```
testSeq1 :: Int -> (Int,Int)
testSeq1 n = impl n (0,0) where
    impl 0 (a,b) = (a,b)
    impl i (a,b) = seq a $ seq b $ impl (i-1) (a+1, b+1)

testSeq2 :: Int -> (Int,Int)
testSeq2 n = impl n (0,0) where
    impl 0 acc = acc
    impl i acc = seq acc $ impl (i-1) ((fst acc)+1, (snd acc)+1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`seq` only forces the evaluation of its first argument shallowly. You can see these two examples:

```
errorTuple :: (Int, Int)
errorTuple = undefined

errorTupleContents :: (Int, Int)
errorTupleContents = (undefined, undefined)

case1 = errorTuple `seq` (1, 1)
case2 = errorTupleContents `seq` (1, 1)
```

`case1` will fail with an `undefined` error, because `seq` tries to force the evaluation of `errorTuple`, which is `undefined`, however, `case2` will not, because the tuple constructor is evaluated and returns a tuple whose contents are unevaluated. If they were evaluated, they'd be `undefined`.

Comment: Is this special treatment for tuple constructors, or are you saying that evaluation does not occur for arguments to any constructors? Suppose that I had created my own tuple data type instead of using the built-in tuples, would the result have been the same ?

Comment: This is not special to tuples; this happens because Haskell is lazy, and only evaluates as much as necessary. You can test this by doing a similar example with `Just undefined` instead, or your own datatype.

Comment: This comes as a shock to me. I thought the whole point of seq was to be able to override the default 'laziness' of Haskell and force it to fully evaluate an expression. This explains why my attempts to use foldl' have not worked as I expected - I was using tuple constructors in my accumulator functions.

Comment: @BillyBadBoy That is the whole point of seq, but lazy/strict is not an all or nothing proposition; data structures can have many fields and be deeply nested, and if you call a fully lazy function while implementing a function it may well make sense to eagerly evaluate parts but not all of such a structure. seq is basically the "minimum unit" of added strictness. There's also a deepseq which does fully evaluate things, but that comes at a cost (traversing the entire structure to check for thunks).

Answer (score 7):

`seq`ing a tuple only forces it to be evaluated as much as to expose its tuple constructor, but will not evaluate its components.

That is,

```
let pair = id (1+1, 2+2)
in seq pair $ ...
```

will apply `id` and produce `(_thunk1, _thunk2)` where the `_thunk`s point to the additions, which are not evaluated at this time.

In your second example, you are forcing the accumulator `acc`, but not its components, hence some large thunks still build up.

You could use a so-called evaluation strategy such as:

```
evalPair :: (a,b) -> ()
evalPair (a,b) = seq a $ seq b ()

testSeq2 :: Int -> (Int,Int)
testSeq2 n = impl n (0,0) where
impl 0 acc = acc
impl i acc = seq (evalPair acc) $ impl (i-1) ((fst acc)+1, (snd acc)+1)
```

But then, `testSeq1` is a simpler approach.

As another alternative, use [strict tuples](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict-0.3.2/docs/Data-Strict-Tuple.html). Such tuples never have thunks for components, but only evaluated results. Forcing the tuple constructor will then force the components as well, as you expected.

```
import Data.Strict.Tuple

testSeq2 :: Int -> Pair Int Int
testSeq2 n = impl n (0 :!: 0) where
impl 0 acc = acc
impl i acc = seq acc $ impl (i-1) ((fst acc + 1) :!: (snd acc + 1))
```